# Mako, Babel and string interpolation

Tags: python, mako, python-babel

I'm trying to do something like this:

`${_('Hello ${name}, welcome to...', mapping=dict(name='${name}'))}`

Where `_()` is my Babel translation function, the first `${name}` is string interpolation I'd like to be performed by Babel and the second `${name}` I'd like to be replaced by Mako so the value is the value in the Python dictionary:

This is ultimately rendered as:

`Hello ${name}, welcome to...`

Not desirable. Problem seems to be that since the second `${name}` is nested inside another `${}`, it's not evaluated.

What I'm aiming for:

`Hello Ryan, welcome to...`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Why not use Python's string formatting?

```
${ _('Hello {name}, welcome to ...').format(name=name) }
```